An example of an even and injective function
What happens if I define a function so that its domain is the set $\{0\} $ and its codomain is the set of real numbers? Would $f(x) = x$ be injective and even at the same time?
$f(x) = f(-x)$
$f(0) = f(-0)$
$0 = 0$
$f(x) = f(y) \implies x=y$
$f(0) = f(-0) \implies 0=-0$
What am I missing?

Sure, it's both even and injective.  Not a very interesting example of either, but it works.  If are are suggesting that someone claimed that there were no such examples, I'd imagine that they had different domains in mind.

Oh, thanks. I was under the impression that an even function can never be injective. What are some interesting examples?

Well, depends what you mean.  In fields of characteristic $2$, $-x=x$ so any injective function works.    The idea behind saying something like "even rules out injective" is that, as soon as you have some $x$ in the domain for which $-x\neq x$ then we get $f(x)=f(-x)$, contradicting injectivity.  So you are down to situations in which $x=-x$ for every point in the domain.

Here is another function that is even and injective: $\emptyset:\emptyset \to \Bbb R$. Again, not really interesting.

No, you are not missing anything. This function (defined on $\{0\}$) is both even and injective.
As @lulu pointed out in the comments, it's not an interesting example of either property. In fact, any function $f:\{0\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is even and injective. Can you see why?
The reason why you thought that functions cannot be both even and injective is because it's not possible if the domain is $\mathbb{R}$. In fact, in some sense, there aren't any interesting examples of a function with both properties. Why? For some set $A$, let $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function. If $A\cap(-A)$ is nonempty, or equivalently if there is $x\in A$ such that $-x$ in $A$, can $f$ be both injective and even? See what happens if you assume it has both properties.
